# Sending data from server to React Native app

Tags: react-native, server

I want to add payment system to my application. I read a documentation and they said that after payment they will send request to my URL. What URL is it, how to send request to my app

Answer (score 0):

It it probably the URL of you backend.
Then you should handle the part where your backend send the response (success, failure etc...) back to your app

Comment: is it possible to do that without backend, only on my mobile application

Comment: what if I will open webkit on my app and try to get callback data

Comment: It  depends of the payment system are you using. Which one ?